# what to ask the interviewer in a software engineering hiring interview

Tags: interviewing, recruitment, human-resources

I have an interview with Amazon, I passed the first exam and about to have the second assessment. I think it is a good idea to ask them some questions to show them that I'm interested in their position.

For me personally I care about team working; so I will ask them how do they work as a team? Will they assign a task for me and let me work on it, what if I stuck? will they review? ...

What other potential questions that I can ask?

Answer (score 2):

I could list a thousand questions that you could ask. Maybe even two thousand. Since space here is limited I think I'll abstain from doing so because you would probably not really be interested in reading any of them anyway.

Only you can decide what you should be asking. Ask about things you want to know more about. Ask about things you are concerned about. Ask about things you expect to get out of the interview.

The nature of your question suggests that you are unsure about your self confidence going into this interview. I think that you should be well rested, clear headed and feeling good about yourself and what you can bring to the position as you go into the interview. Questions to ask should come naturally and not some preconceived list that you rattle off.

Comment: I don't agree that the questions should come during the interview. because the recruter asked me to prepare some questions. That's why I need some insigts from this site

Comment: I agree with your first 2 paragraphs (even if those read more like a comment than an answer), but I very much disagree with your last paragraph - questions just don't come naturally to all of us in such scenarios, regardless of self-confidence and clear-headedness, and for us coming up with a few ahead of time is definitely the way to go.